# TYPO3: images, thumbnails not displayed

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In a fresh 7.6.15 installation on a Ubuntu 16 VM with the introduction package, images and their thumbnails are not displayed.  GraphicsMagick is installed.  GFX configuration is modified with the install tool per the [wiki document](https://wiki.typo3.org/GraphicsMagick). No php errors listed in `php_errors.log`. Images are listed in `Filelist`.

Comment: does the image manipulation check of the Install Tool work?
can IM/GM write their files? check the folders in the Install Tool: are all existent? are all writable? are the default filemasks working?
use developmode to get errormessages.

Comment: Image manipulation `Convert images...` fails with `ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick handling is enabled, but the execute command returned an error`.  Configuration double-checked against wiki - no errors found. Dev mode yields no error messages in log or on screen. Folder structure: Either `CMS default` or `Don't need to be fixed`. Ghostscript is installed. As I am new to TYPO3, I think I've covered all your suggestions but cannot be certain.

Comment: I think your path to IM/GM is wrong. Ghostscript is only necessary if you want PDFs be handled as images = not necessary for the usual image handling. be aware that IM/GM can be installed in unusual places and you have to enter the correct path (otherwise TYPO3 could always guess the path)

Comment: You're right about the path.  The answer below got me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of GraphicsMagick in the installtool might be wrong

[GFX][im_path]

[GFX][im_path_lzw]

On my Ubuntu server the path is /usr/bin/

Other common value is /usr/local/bin/

Comment: Thanks. Just goes to show - following documentation is not always the right path.